# IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript wait until ajax done

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im creating c# Selenim Webdriver application

when i traying call javascript function on c# ,executeScript return null or "" value.

**How can i wait until called functions inside ajax is done**

Sorry for my english

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 String Myresponse = (String)js.ExecuteScript("return getUrl(" + MyUrL+ ");");
 richTextBox1.Text = Myresponse;
```

**in Javascript file my function**

```
function getUrl(gUrl){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: gUrl, 
    }).done(function(d) {
        return "Success";

    }).fail(function(a) {
       return "Fail";
    }); 

 }
```

Comment: @DebanjanB Your links not my answer ,Please re check my question.

Comment: @DebanjanB
I want detect  javascript function was finished not check document readystate change .

im waiting  is this ajax  finished, i was solved other way (create element and set value to ajax answer and read this element value from c#) bu not clean for me.

function getUrl(gUrl){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: gUrl, 
    }).done(function(d) {
        return "Success";

    }).fail(function(a) {
       return "Fail";
    }); 

 }